# Tool bar in the fragment looks like a navigation drawer, how to make it a normal toolbar with a drop down menu

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have been trying to add a custom made toolbar drop-down menu to a fragment that is linked to a navigation drawer menu but the tool bare just looks like another half-baked navigation drawer.
hears a pic of the messed-up toolbar drop-down menu
[image: the messed-up toolbar drop-down menu]

just so you won't be confused heres the fully fuctioning Navigation drawer
[image: the fully fuctioning Navigation drawer]

just to let you know in the `styles.xml` resource file I removed the default tool bar by typing `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`

here's the fragmant's layout called fragment_student.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.isaacdixon.navigation.StudentFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_student" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Student"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>



    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_view"
        app:menu="@menu/student_menu"
        >

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</FrameLayout>
```

here's the fragment_student.xml menu, its for the drop-down tool bar

- ```
  <item android:id="@+id/student_tb_settings"
      android:title="Settings"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_person_black_24dp"/>

  <item android:id="@+id/student_tb_other"
      android:title="Other"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_settings_black_24dp"/>
  ```

here's the StudentFragment.java file

```
package com.example.isaacdixon.navigation;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class StudentFragment extends Fragment {


    public StudentFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_student, container, false);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are doing everything wrong. You should be having DrawerLayout as the top view that contains content view and the navigation view.

I would suggest you to go through the following tutorial:

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer

Comment: sorry but you don't understand I'm not trying to make a navigation drawer( I already did that), I'm trying to make a tool bar with a drop-down menu